# Generalisation of Seiberg-Witten Map?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, non-commutative-theory

Given the following algebra,
$$[\hat{x}_i,\hat{p}_j] = i\hbar\delta_{ij};~[\hat{x}_i,\hat{x}_j] = i\theta_{ij};~[\hat{p}_i,\hat{p}_j] = i\eta_{ij}$$
in a space, where $\theta_{ij},\eta_{ij}$ are constants. For simplicity, assume only 2 dimensions, $x,y$ (and $\theta_{ij}$ as $\theta$, $\eta_{ij}$ as $\eta$). One can transform to a set of commuting operators $(x,p)$ (denoting them by removing the hat) as (Seiberg-Witten map),
$$\hat{x} = x - \frac{\theta}{2\hbar}p_y;~\hat{y} = y + \frac{\theta}{2\hbar}p_x$$
and,
$$\hat{p}_x = p_x + \frac{\eta}{2\hbar}y;~ \hat{p}_y = p_y - \frac{\eta}{2\hbar}x$$

This can be easily verified that the $(x_i,p_j)$ commute.

My question is, in the case of more general algebra, say,
$$[\hat{x}_i,\hat{p}_j] = i\hbar f_{ij}(\hat{x},\hat{p});~[\hat{x}_i,\hat{x}_j] = i\Theta_{ij}(\hat{x},\hat{p});~[\hat{p}_i,\hat{p}_j] = i\zeta_{ij}(\hat{x},\hat{p})$$
does there exist a method to obtain a set of commuting variables?

Comment: Method? Beyond Ansatz blood sweat and tears?  Conceivably [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(91)90216-D) might give you a flavor of the incessant ferment of the pas 30 years....